# Como faço uma função em C que remove um caracter digitado pelo usuário da frase que ele digitou? Não conseguir fazer a função

Tags: c

//Ex: se o usuário digita 'ola mundo' e digita 'o' em seguida, o programa deve retornar la mund, removendo a letra que o usuário digitou.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(){
    char str[20],ch;
    int i, n, j;
    printf("Digite uma frase:\n");
    scanf("%s",str);
    printf("Digite uma letra dessa frase:\n");
    scanf("%c",&ch);
    n=strlen(str);

    for(i=0, j=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        if(str[i]!=ch)
        {
            str[j]=str[i];
            j++;
        }
    }
    str[j]='\0';
    printf("removemos a letra digitada: %s\n", str);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Da maneira como fez, utilizando `scanf("%s",str);`, só conseguirá ler uma única palavra, pois o espaço é considerado um delimitador pela função scanf e interrompe a leitura. Tente `scanf("%[^\n]",str);`, ler até encontrar um caractere fim de linha ('\n').

Comment: Outro problema que pode ocorrer é que sua leitura da letra a ser removida pode pegar algo do buffer de entrada que não seja a letra que você informou. Eliminando estes problemas seu código roda corretamente. Veja: https://ideone.com/VOgx6r